How to change factor levels to grayscale when used as vertex.color in igraph
I am using a factor to color in different vertices in igraph, but need it to be black and white for submission. I found this answer, but it doesn't work. Below is sample code.
nodes <- c("A","B","C","D")
chars <- c(1,0,0,1)
nodelist <- as.data.frame(cbind(nodes, chars))
edges <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("A","B",1),c("A","C",0),c("A","D",0),c("B","C",1),c("B","D",0),c("C","D",1)))

chars <- as.factor(chars)
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, nodes, directed=FALSE)
plot(g, vertex.color = chars)

looks nice, but needs to be black and white
colorset = c("0"='white',"1"='black')
plot(g, vertex.color = colorset)

in black and white, but it messes up the factor levels

You can assign specific properties to each of the vertices in your graph. For example
chars <- as.factor(chars)
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, nodes, directed=FALSE)
colorset = c('white','black')
invcolorset = c('black', 'white')
V(g)$color <- colorset[chars]
V(g)$label.color <- invcolorset[chars]
plot(g)



You can try label and levels for chars
chars <- factor(chars, label = c("black","white"))
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, nodes, directed = FALSE)
plot(g, vertex.color = levels(chars))


